# Функция COUNT в sql

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, ну могу понять функцию COUNT в sql. Хочу вывести количество полей, где tovarID равен 15, делаю запрос

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE tovarID='15'");
echo "$res";
```

Результат получается такой: `Resource id #49`, что это значит, я не пойму... товаров у меня всего 28, а там, где tovarID равен 15, - 4 товара.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$res - это ресурс запроса. Из него ты можешь уже извлечь массив или запись одну:

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($res));
```

Кроме того при использовании COUNT (а так же MAX MIN) надо добавлять в запрос GROUP BY

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE tovarID='15' GROUP BY tovarID;
```

Comment: Вот что получил: `Array ( [0] => 4 )`, то есть правильно 4 товара. Но мне нужна всего лишь одна циферка 4; Как извлечь из этого массива `print_r(mysql_fetch_row($res));` последнюю цифру?

Comment: `$res = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE tovarID='15' GROUP BY tovarID")); echo $res[0];`

Comment: @sambady 
GROUP BY здесь не нужен, т.к. группа всего одна.